# Keras vs Tensorflow Estimators

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I have the following question:
I have written that you have two options in developing a Classification model in tensorflow. One is with KerasClassifier and the second one is with tf.estimator.LinearClassification.
Now my question because I have written that keras is just a wrapper for tensorflow: Are the two options the same algorithms? Is KerasClassifier the same than LinearClassification just wrapped?

Comment: I think it link can answer ur question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51455863/whats-the-difference-between-a-tensorflow-keras-model-and-estimator

Comment: yes, I have already read this one. But it doesn't answer if the KerasClassifier is an high-abstracted version of the LinearClassifier of Tensorflow.Estimator, does it?