# AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'load_weights'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have build and trained Artificial Neural Network model. Now I wanted to load the weights. I used **estimator.load_weights(checkpoint_path)**. After that I am getting below error.

*AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'load_weights'*

checkpoint_path is completely fine as **checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt",
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)**
is successfully executed
&
**estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, epochs=1000, batch_size=10, verbose=1)**

Answer (score 1):

`estimator` is part of the Estimator API, and is a wrapper for the tensorflow `model`. See docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) and an ineresting discussion of the Estimator API in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51455864/11080708).

`load_weights` is a `model` method. As indicated in the error message, your estimator is a KerasRegressor object, which wraps a model but is not a model itself.

You can use `estimator.model` to access the model attribute of the estimator object.

So, to load saved weights you can use `estimator.model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`.